# How to make fields unique with other models referencing the same ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a way to make model fields unique with other models referencing the same ForeignKey?

In my case I am trying to make it so that the `names` of `Attribute` models with the same `Obj` are unique. Ex: if there exists a `CharAttribute` with `name='Types'` and `obj=1` there can't be another `CharAttribute` with `name='Types'` and `obj=1` nor an `IntAttribute` with `name='Types'` and `obj=1`

```
class Obj (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)


class CharAttribute (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Obj, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class IntAttribute (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Obj, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My current idea for a solution would be something like this:

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
    super().clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
    for other_name in IntAttribute.objects.filter(obj=self.obj):
        if self.name == other_name:
            raise ValidationError(
                ('Attributes of the same object may not have the same name, %(name) s already exists for '
                 '%(object) s' % {'name': self.name, 'object': self.obj.name})
            )

    for other_name in CharAttribute.objects.filter(obj=self.obj):
        if self.name == other_name:
            raise ValidationError(
                ('Attributes of the same object may not have the same name, %(name) s already exists for '
                 '%(object) s' % {'name': self.name, "object": self.obj.name})
            )
```

But creating another for loop for each possible future created `Attribute` feels repetitive and there must be a better way of accomplishing this task.

Thank you in advance for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together) to make sure no combination of fields is repeated in a model:

```
class CharAttribute (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Obj, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'obj')
```

Between models you would have to do a manual validation:

```
class CharAttribute (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    obj = models.ForeignKey(Obj, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'obj')

    def clean(self):
        if IntAttribute.objects.filter(name=self.name, obj=self.obj).exists():
            raise ValidationError('...')
```

The same method applies for the other model.

Comment: I feel like an idiot with the for loops, thank you haha